# How to convert XML to EVTX?

Tags: xml, windows, event-viewer

I exported the event viewer logs and saved them accedently as xml file. Can i convert them to evtx? Or can i view the xml with the event viewer of windows?

I cannot get those event viewer logs back, so this xml file is the my last chance. I just need to know, why the pc shut down by itself on a specific time and date.